# Build 32bit .EXE Visual Basic Express 2010

Tags: vb.net, 32bit-64bit

I have Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit and Visual Basic Express 2010.

I want to know if the exe files that I build from my PC are 64-bit or 32-bit.

Also, if my exe files are for 64-bit machines, how can I convert them for 32-bit Windows?

Comment: Why downvoting guys?

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site! Downvote because, per the downvote mouseover, "this question does not show any research effort." Also, this isn't a great question for StackOverflow. I recommend you read [the entire Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and head back when you have a specific, programming-related question.

Comment: VB 2010 builds managed (.NET) executables, which are 32 or 64 bit depending on the version of the framework the app runs on, so an app is 32-bit when run on a 32-bit version of Windows and 64-bit under a 64-bit Windows.

Comment: So I don't have to worry?

Comment: @Nonickplease: Sort of. Unless you have a dependency which only supports x86, or you want to avoid the headache of managing different DLLs for each x86 and x64. Example - Oracle or SQLite client.

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure this by the following in Visual Studio:

Go to Project menu item ---->> Properties ->>>Compile tab

then look on that page for Target CPU, switch it to x86 for 32 bit systems.

As far as converting your existing Exe's, you would probably have to recompile them using the above mentioned settings.

> [Video Tutorial](http://syntaxbytes.com/wordpress/2014/10/27/specifying-32-bit-or-64-bit-application/)

[image]

Comment: There is no such an option In project's menu.Can you post a screenshot please?

Comment: I have added the screen shot